# CPP Code randomly freezes from reading IO

Tags: c++, io, freeze

I am trying to read values in linux. I have traced the issue to it being from reading chronyc sources, but I dont know why. It also freezes at random times (like on iteration 100, 250, or 11001), so its not consistent. It just consistently wont finish all the iterations. It also works on a different but identical computer which makes this more odd.

from my code, this didnt freeze:

```
void writeTime(){
    FILE *hour;
    FILE *nano;
    char line[9];
    char nLine[10]; 
    system("date +%R.%S |cat >time.txt");
    hour = fopen("time.txt","r");
    fgets(line,9,hour);
    myfile<<line<<".";
    fclose(hour);
    system("date +%N |cat >epoch.txt");
    nano = fopen("epoch.txt","r");
    fgets(nLine,10,nano);
    myfile<<nLine<<",";
    fclose(nano);
}
```

but this did

```
void ntpSync(){
    char ntp[]= <Insert NTP IP Here>;
    FILE *jitter;
    char line[100];
    char *start;
    char *i;
    system("chronyc sources |cat > offset.txt");
    jitter = fopen("offset.txt", "r");
    fgets(line,100,jitter);
    fgets(line,100,jitter);
    fgets(line,100,jitter);
    fgets(line,100,jitter);
        i=strstr(line,ntp);
            start = strpbrk(line,"+-");
            myfile<<start;
    fclose(jitter);
}
```

Theyre similar and should work, but for some reason only writeTime doesn't freeze. Does anyone know why or have any idea why? Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I had it previously as the code below because it was a lot nicer, but it froze

```
void ntpSync(){
    char ntp[]= <insert NTP IP>;
    FILE *jitter;
    char line[100];
    char *start;
    char *i;
    system("chronyc sources|cat > offset.txt");
    jitter = fopen("offset.txt","r");
    fgets(line,100,jitter);
    while(!feof(jitter))
{   
    i=strstr(line,ntp);
    if(i!=NULL){
        start = strpbrk(line,"+-"); 
        myfile<<start;  
    }
    fgets(line,100,jitter);
}
    fclose(jitter);
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `system` call, and use the same `offset.txt` file twice in a row? How long is that file, anyway?

Comment: @samvarshavchik so I am trying to use the debugger gdb, but it seems like I need to know where itll freeze? Each iteration is a second long, so do you have any advice on how to debug it? no matter where i put breakpoints, ill have to wait and keep inputting c until it freezes??

Comment: @beta if it just reads from offset.txt, i believe it works (i'm running the code for hours and it didnt freeze at 4 hrs). The file is super small, just a couple hundred bytes. (literally only about 400 characters long). Issue it, I need to read from that call, otherwise my data is invalid

Comment: You can tell gdb to run the program. When it freezes you can usually ctrl-c to break, and then look at the backtrace.

Comment: It looks like it could be a memory issue? Both the debugger and free running code froze at the same time.
From the backtrace, I dont seem to get much useful info. See below comment for the backtrace info

Comment: #0  0x00007ffff6c8b840 in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6

#1  0x00007ffff6c8b6f4 in sleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6

#2  0x00007ffff7560eb9 in std::this_thread::__sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1l> >, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6

#3  0x0000000000402ada in void std::this_thread::sleep_for<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >(std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) ()

#4-6 removed due to character length. it was just where the main called the func
@samvarshavchik